# 403 header response code

Tags: wordpress, 301-redirect, 403-forbidden

I am getting a 403 header response code for my website while checking this tool https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Here is the screenshot below: https://snipboard.io/p2DH1S.jpg

Here are the .htaccess details:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I do not understand how would I solve it Could anyone please tell me how I can fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the  `E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` line?

Comment: No, I haven't. Shall I delete it? Anything else that I need to add there if I delete the line?

Comment: It seems, @Tim R's suggestion does helps  and access is OK now?